# How to save a int in a android app for when the app is reopen

Tags: android, save, int, savechanges

When my app is running it receives a number(id) that it's used for a notification.

I need to save this number for when i reopen the application, the number can be retrieve, and the application doesn't trow a notification of the same id.

Any suggestions on how to do this will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html for saving data. saved data can be retrieve from SharedPreferences